# C++ - Gettings size from vector in FOR loop

Tags: c++, vector, for-loop

I have a loop that asks for user input, and adds it too a vector, then when if they type "EXIT" it will stop and display the list. What I am trying to do now is determine the number of elements with `size()`

This is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    write(1,"\E[H\E[2J",7);                                  
    vector<string> list;
    cout << "Enter UIDs: \n\n"; 
    for(string uid ; cin >> uid && uid != "EXIT"; list.push_back(uid))
        cout << " \n";
    copy(list.begin(), list.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n\n"));
    cout << "Vector size: " << uid.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When attempting to compile that I get the error:

g++ sof.cpp -o sof

> sof.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   sof.cpp:16:32: error: name lookup of ‘uid’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping
>   sof.cpp:13:16: error:   cannot use obsolete binding at ‘uid’ because it has a destructor

Comment: `uid` doesn't exist on line 16; it's only within the scope of the `for` loop.  (HINT: you don't have any braces around your loop stuff).

Comment: I have edited to format your code apropriatley.  This should highlight the point made by @OliCharlesworth that you are missing braces for the body of the for loop.

Comment: @JonTaylor Not really, the code needs no braces. The error is the `uid.size()` call, which should be `list.size()`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth actually, there's no need for braces here.

Comment: @juanchopanza yeah I realised once I looked at the code again, but the format still helps.

Comment: Your code will break as soon as you decide you need to `#include <list>` for something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're querying `uid.size()` instead of `list.size()`